# Visual Studio 2017 setup project missing

Tags: visual-studio, installshield, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-setup-proje

Anyone know where the elusive setup project template went to for Visual Studio 2017?
Trying to update VS2015 setup projects, but their setup projects are not supported and MS has no information I can find (I followed every link in their forums from the IDE for the last 5 hours, but they take me to old pages!).
InstallShield is nowhere to be found & ClickOnce is still not an option.

Comment: Missing installer project templates since Visual Studio 2017 Update 15.9.6 , I've reported to VS team but seems like they don't even want to accept their mistake.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/442945/visual-studio-2017-version-1596-missing-installer.html

Answer (score 53):

Full explained and working solution:

1) open vs2017 and select "Tools" -> "Extensions and Updates"

2) Under Extensions and Updates select "Online" on the left of the window and on the right type in search box "Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension" hit enter and it is the first download in result (attached image) select this result "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects" and click on "Download"

3) You will have to restart your VS2017 for the installation to happen so click on "close" button then restart you VS2017 then you should have it!

4) To use it you right click on your "Solution abc" then "Add New Project" under "Other Project Types" select "Visual Studio Installer" as I did in this attachment below.

[image: Second image is the result and First image is the search for this project template]

[image]

Comment: after doing all these, VS was still unable to load already existing setup project in the solution - right-clicking on the project and reloading worked at last, thanks.

Comment: Pretty useful. I searched similarly for VS 2015 and got it for 2015. After clicking Download I got a VSI.exe. Thanks, that helped very much.

Comment: Thank you so much it help me alot

Answer (score 25):

I finally found it. I had to look in the RC forum postings.

Visual Studio Marketplace: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)

Answer (score 2):

InstallShield support for Visual Studio 2017 is available from Flexera since April-May of 2018.

You can find it on Visual MarketPlace :https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Flexera-InstallShield-Lite.InstallShield2018Lite

you can find support via their community forum:
https://community.flexerasoftware.com/forumdisplay.php?348-InstallShield-2018-Lite

You can give a try :-)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21114323)

Comment: Yes ashok,you are correct.There is no Limited edition support for VS2017.InstallShield 2018 Lite is a paid edition.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects should help you build installers. Its what am using to generate .exe for my applications developed in visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

Limited Edition InstallShield is not available for VS2017. I think people has purchase Express Edition 2016 to create basic setup like LE.

Answer (score 0):

There are several 3rd party extensions available for creating Setup projects (like other installation systems: NSIS and Inno Setup etc.).

Search the Visual Studio Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unSignedsro.VisualInstaller