# VS2017 Setup Project - Where?

Tags: c#, installation, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a setup project / installer for a C# project but can't find the 'setup project' template in VS2017.

In VS2015 it was under:
Other Project Types >> Setup and Deployment >> Visual Studio Installer
and I used that several times without any problem.

That is not present on my VS2017. Is there something else I need to install?

I've looked through all the installed options and also tried the Online section, but searching for 'Setup' only brings up 'Mastercam NET-Hook'.

I've also looked on Stack Overflow but all the questions appear to be about problems within a Setup Project and not creating it in the first place.

Google brings up lots of questions for earlier versions (2013 etc) but nothing I could see for VS2017.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837690/visual-studio-2017-setup-project-missing/46531135#46531135

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You must use the official Microsoft extension to do that, it's available [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)!

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, after adding this addin, now, whenever I open a Class file (*.cs) in VS2017, it opens the file in Designer   (rather in than Code View).  (These are pure Class files, not .aspx files with a .cs code-behind.)  Huh?!   This is sooooooo dumb....

Answer (score 8):

You need to install the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects". Open up MSVS Tools->Extensions and Updates (Extensions and Updates popup form appears) Online->Visual Studio Marketplace->Tools->Setup & Deployment. Then select "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects" (today, August 20, 2018, the version is 0.8.8).

NOTES: These are more of the classical MS installers we all know and love used since VS6 days.

Comment: It appears to have changed the name to "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" at version 0.9.0 as that also works with VS2019.