# Windows Installer is missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to installable windows application but in Prerequisities list **Windows Installer** is missing.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 setup project missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837690/visual-studio-2017-setup-project-missing)

Comment: @SeM that is not the issue.. i have installed what said in that case.. but i showed in image that windows installer option is missing

Comment: It is gone, won't be back.  You never needed it before, its only use was to update the OS on ancient machines that are not being maintained by its user.  The kind that you cannot support yourself.  Minimum system requirements for your installer is XP SP3 or Win2003 SP2.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/released-versions-of-windows-installer

Comment: @HansPassant Means i can make installable application without it?

Comment: Yes, that's what "you never needed it before" means.  Just try it by yourself.